# What can we say about the optimal value of the following optimization problem if the constraint is changed?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have following optimization problem $$\textbf{P1. }\min.~ \|AX-B\|_F^2 \\ \text{s.t.}~~~~ \|X\|_F^2=c \\ ~~~~\|X-M\|_F^2\leq z,$$ where $A,B,M,c,z$ are the constants and $X$ is the optimization variable. Also, $\|X\|_F$ means the Frobenius norm. How does the optimal value of the above optimization problem is affected if we increase $c$? I have following explanation (which I think is clearly wrong) to show that the optimal value increases with increase in $c$.

My explanation:

We know that $\|X-M\|_F^2= \|X\|_F^2+\|M\|_F^2-2\operatorname{Tr}(X^TM)$ and hence the second constraint ($\|X-M\|_F^2\leq z$) can be written as $$\|X\|_F^2+\|M\|_F^2-2\operatorname{Tr}(X^TM) \leq z$$. Now using the first constraint ($\|X\|_F^2=c$) we have $$c+\|M\|_F^2-z \leq 2\operatorname{Tr}(X^TM)$$. Hence, the overall optimization problem becomes $$\textbf{P2  }\min.~ \|AX-B\|_F^2 \\ s.t.~~~~ c+\|M\|_F^2-z \leq 2\operatorname{Tr}(X^TM).$$ Now, in my opinion if we increase the value of $c$, then the optimal value should increase since the constraint becomes more tight. But this leads to the conclusion that the optimal value of $\textbf{P2}$ is lowest when $c=0$. However, $c=0$ may not satisfy the constraints of $\textbf{P1}$. Where am I wrong in my explanation? And how to know what affect $c$ has on the optimal value of $\textbf{P1}$?

Comment: What does the $F$ mean?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews it means Frobenious norm. I have also added this to my post.

Comment: If you don't notice the difference between $||a||$ and $\|a\|,$ look at the difference between $||a|| ||b||$ and $\|a\|\|b\|,$ respectively coded as `||a|| ||b||` and `\|a\|\|b\|`. And between $2\text{Tr}(A)$ and $2\operatorname{Tr}(A).$ The latter way of coding it results in context-dependent spacing, so that $2\operatorname{Tr}A$ has more space to the right of $\operatorname{Tr}$ than does $\operatorname{Tr}(A),$ by operation of the software without deliberation by the user.

Comment: @MichaelHardy thanks for the comment. I will be more careful in future.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed your explanation is wrong.
Take two different values $c_1,c_2$. Then the sets $\{\|X\|^2=c_1\}$ and
$\{\|X\|^2=c_2\}$
are disjoint. So we cannot say one of the is tighter than the other.

Consider the following simplified situation: $\min (x-1)^2$ under the constraint $|x|=c$. Then $x=c$ is the solution with optimal value $(c-1)^2$, which is not  a monotone function.